# Creating signatures for book printing

Tags: pdfpages, octavo

I reviewed previous questions on topic but there is something I don't understand. I'm using pdfpages to create signature of 16 pages each for book binding. I can produce 8 physical pages in the right order each with 2 logical pages. BUT I would like 2 physical pages each with 8 logical pages. How do I obtain this? I tried to change the nup command but it does not produce any difference in output. What am I missing?

PS: My workaround is to produce a first file, then `treat' it again with pdfpages, and then treat again this file. I also have to set manually the dimensions of the pdf each time. These 3 passages are necessary to produce sheets of 8 logical pages on each side, ready to produce 16 pages signatures.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{octavo}

\usepackage[]{pdfpages}

%\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth % for xelatex
%\pdfpageheight=\paperheight % for xelatex

\usepackage[paperwidth=132mm, paperheight=186mm]  {geometry}
    
    
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1-16}, nup=4x2, signature=16,
                landscape]{file.pdf}
                
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the `booklet` package can help by generating a document printed in signatures.

Comment: The signatures of pdfpages are meant to be folded once without cutting, which is really the simplest signature. You cannot create signatures which are meant to be folded twice or more time to be cut eventually. I.e. mixing of options `signature` and `nup` is not supported.

Comment: Thanks this is clear. Will try to see the booklet package.

Comment: For the benefit of others who find this question via search: If you are submitting your book PDF to a print-on-demand service, rather than binding it yourself, then you do not need to create signatures (and should not do it). They do it.

Comment: I know. But few copies have been bound manually. Then yes, when I sent the book to the publisher, they have their own printing routine and no need for my signatures. So I just needed to send the pdf. I guess its is the same for print on demand services.